# flutter firebase Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.

i already added "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();" in main. and added "FirebaseApp.configure()" in AppDelegate.swift .
and also added GoogleService-Info.plist into runner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.